# Herramientas de depuración para Python

Tags: python, depuración

En Python existen algunas librerías para depurar código como `cProfile` donde puedes seguir la traza de ejecución de un programa como por ejemplo:

```
import cProfile, pstats, StringIO
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

# Nuestro código
result = [i for i in range(10)]

print(result)
pr.disable()
s = StringIO.StringIO()
sortby = 'cumulative'
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print s.getvalue()
```

Nos daría como resultado:

```
   2 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Pero me gustaría saber, ¿qué librerías o herramientas existen para  seguimiento del flujo de ejecución de un programa complejo donde existen cientos o miles ejecuciones de una manera más simple?

Comment: Hola @avara. Lastimosamente, este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas no se pueden realizar en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedes acceder al [salón de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde esas preguntas son bienvenidas puesto que el chat es más informal y las personas cuentan sus opiniones sobre diversos temas. Solo haz click en el enlace de este comentario.

Comment: Me sorprende la pregunta. No hay ninguna herramienta que haga fácil  seguir el flujo de ejecución de un programa complejo con miles de instrucciones. Además, el ejemplo que pones es un **profiler**, útil para identificar partes de tu programa que necesita más optimización. Un **debugger** es otra cosa, así otras herramientas afines como **pruebas unitarias**, **cobertura de código**, **chequeo de estilo**,... Algunos IDEs más habituales (Pydev, Pycharm, Spyder,...) integran varias de estas herramientas. Échales un vistazo.

Comment: Con test unitarios, como bien indicas, podemos analizar cuanto porcentaje de nuestro código hemos validado y "la calidad" del código si usamos Pylint por ejemplo, pero en cuanto al rendimiento y consumo de memoria, hasta donde he podido investigar estos días desde que hice la pregunta, he encontrado que exportando los resultados con Cprofiler u otras como Yappi, se pueden interpretar los datos con KCachegrind de una manera más amigable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esto puede estar ligado directamente a opciones personales, voy a mencionar el debugger que viene por defecto en Python y al final te dejo la lista de otros debuggers para que los pruebes y elijas el que te conviene más.

### Python Debugger

Python tiene si propio Debugger llamado [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). Lo usas como usarías los breakpoints dentro de tu código, es decir, lo puedes usar en donde lo necesitas y cuantas veces quieras.

La forma de uso más común es mediante la función [`pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace). Considera el siguiente script de ejemplo:

```
# test.py
lista = range(4, 10)
for elemento in lista:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    elemento **= 2
```

Al ejecutarlo:

```
$ python test.py
```

Vas a ver algo como esto:

```
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(5)<module>()
-> elemento **= 2
(Pdb)
```

Al ver `(Pdb)` te indica que se ha detenido la ejecución del programa y está a la espera de algún comando de depuración:

```
(Pdb)
```

La línea anterior a `(Pdb)` te indica la línea que va a ser ejecutada a continuación:

```
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(4)<module>()
-> elemento **= 2
```

Que equivale a la línea 4 de tu script. Antes de continuar, puedes ver los comandos disponibles pulsando `h` o `?`:

```
(Pdb) h
Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    bt         cont      enable  jump  pp       run      unt   
a      c          continue  exit    l     q        s        until 
alias  cl         d         h       list  quit     step     up    
args   clear      debug     help    n     r        tbreak   w     
b      commands   disable   ignore  next  restart  u        whatis
break  condition  down      j       p     return   unalias  where 

Miscellaneous help topics:
==========================
exec  pdb

Undocumented commands:
======================
retval  rv

(Pdb)
```

No vamos a entrar en detalle sobre todos los comandos que se pueden usar, solo algunos básicos. Por ejemplo, el comando `n` o `next` te permite ejecutar la siguiente línea de código que en este caso sería `elemento **= 2`:

```
(Pdb) n
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(2)<module>()
-> for elemento in lista:
(Pdb)
```

Se acaba de ejecutar la línea `elemento **= 2` y, por lo tanto, podríamos tener acceso a su valor, también al valor de la lista que fue definida inicialmente, en realidad, a cualquier variable que haya sido definida hasta ese momento:

```
(Pdb) elemento
16
(Pdb) lista
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
(Pdb)
```

El comando `n` va a continuar en la siguiente línea incluso si esta contiene una función. Considera ahora el siguiente script que usa una función para retornar la potencia de un número:

```
# test.py
def potencia(base, exponente):
    return base ** exponente

lista = range(4, 10)
for elemento in lista:
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
```

Al ejecutarla:

```
$ python test.py
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(7)<module>()
-> elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
(Pdb)
```

Nota que la siguiente línea que sera ejecutada es la llamada la función `potencia`, si usamos `n` va a ejecutar la función y retornar a la siguiente línea que es la siguiente iteración del `for`:

```
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(5)<module>()
-> for elemento in lista:
(Pdb)
```

Pero, ¿qué pasa si queremos saber lo que ejecuta la función `potencia`? Para ese podemos usar el comando `s` o `step`, este comando continuará dentro de la primera línea de la función que ha sido llamada. Si ejecutamos de nuevo:

```
$ python test.py
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(7)<module>()
-> elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(1)potencia()
-> def potencia(base, exponente):
(Pdb) n
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(2)potencia()
-> return base ** exponente
```

Luego tenemos el comando `c` o `continue`, que, como dice su nombre, continúa con la ejecución del programa, pero ya que estamos dentro de un `for` va a continuar hasta que termine de iterar cada elemento. Por lo tanto:

```
$ python test.py
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(7)<module>()
-> elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
(Pdb) c
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(6)<module>()
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) c
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(7)<module>()
-> elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
(Pdb) c
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(6)<module>()
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) c
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(7)<module>()
-> elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
(Pdb) c
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(6)<module>()
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) c
$
```

Para terminar, creo que es necesario también conocer el comando `q` o `quit` que finaliza la ejecución del debugger y el programa es abortado:

```
$ python test.py
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(7)<module>()
-> elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
(Pdb) q
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    elemento = potencia(elemento, 2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 68, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
$
```

Para mayor de detalle sobre los comandos de depuración puedes ver la sección [Debugger Commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

### Python Debugger (con autocomplete)

De hecho, `pdb` reconoce cuando pulsas <kbd>Tab</kbd>, pero solo se limita a mostrarte la lista de comandos. Considera el siguiente script:

```
# test.py
var_a = 10
var_b = [1, 3, 5, 7 ,9]
var_c = 'prueba'
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Al ejecutar:

```
$ python test.py
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(4)<module>()->None
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) [TAB][TAB]
EOF        cl         disable    jump       quit       step       whatis
a          clear      down       l          r          tbreak     where
alias      commands   enable     list       restart    u          
args       condition  exit       n          return     unalias    
b          cont       h          next       retval     unt        
break      continue   help       p          run        until      
bt         d          ignore     pp         rv         up         
c          debug      j          q          s          w          
(Pdb) var_a
10
(Pdb) var_a.[TAB][TAB][TAB]
```

No funciona para ver los métodos de la variable entera `var_a`. Existe un truquito usando la librería [`rlcompleter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/rlcompleter.html). Versión modificada del script:

```
# test.py
import pdb
import rlcompleter

pdb.Pdb.complete = rlcompleter.Completer(locals()).complete

var_a = 10
var_b = [1, 3, 5, 7 ,9]
var_c = 'prueba'
pdb.set_trace()
```

Al ejecutar:

```
$ python test.py
> /home/cesar/Desktop/test/test.py(9)<module>()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) var_a
10
(Pdb) var_a.[TAB][TAB]
var_a.__abs__(           var_a.__lshift__(        var_a.__rpow__(
var_a.__add__(           var_a.__mod__(           var_a.__rrshift__(
var_a.__and__(           var_a.__mul__(           var_a.__rshift__(
var_a.__class__(         var_a.__neg__(           var_a.__rsub__(
var_a.__cmp__(           var_a.__new__(           var_a.__rtruediv__(
var_a.__coerce__(        var_a.__nonzero__(       var_a.__rxor__(
var_a.__delattr__(       var_a.__oct__(           var_a.__setattr__(
var_a.__div__(           var_a.__or__(            var_a.__sizeof__(
var_a.__divmod__(        var_a.__pos__(           var_a.__str__(
var_a.__doc__            var_a.__pow__(           var_a.__sub__(
var_a.__float__(         var_a.__radd__(          var_a.__subclasshook__(
var_a.__floordiv__(      var_a.__rand__(          var_a.__truediv__(
var_a.__format__(        var_a.__rdiv__(          var_a.__trunc__(
var_a.__getattribute__(  var_a.__rdivmod__(       var_a.__xor__(
var_a.__getnewargs__(    var_a.__reduce__(        var_a.bit_length(
var_a.__hash__(          var_a.__reduce_ex__(     var_a.conjugate(
var_a.__hex__(           var_a.__repr__(          var_a.denominator
var_a.__index__(         var_a.__rfloordiv__(     var_a.imag
var_a.__init__(          var_a.__rlshift__(       var_a.numerator
var_a.__int__(           var_a.__rmod__(          var_a.real
var_a.__invert__(        var_a.__rmul__(          
var_a.__long__(          var_a.__ror__(           
(Pdb) var_b
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
(Pdb) var_b.[TAB][TAB]
var_b.__add__(           var_b.__iadd__(          var_b.__setattr__(
var_b.__class__(         var_b.__imul__(          var_b.__setitem__(
var_b.__contains__(      var_b.__init__(          var_b.__setslice__(
var_b.__delattr__(       var_b.__iter__(          var_b.__sizeof__(
var_b.__delitem__(       var_b.__le__(            var_b.__str__(
var_b.__delslice__(      var_b.__len__(           var_b.__subclasshook__(
var_b.__doc__            var_b.__lt__(            var_b.append(
var_b.__eq__(            var_b.__mul__(           var_b.count(
var_b.__format__(        var_b.__ne__(            var_b.extend(
var_b.__ge__(            var_b.__new__(           var_b.index(
var_b.__getattribute__(  var_b.__reduce__(        var_b.insert(
var_b.__getitem__(       var_b.__reduce_ex__(     var_b.pop(
var_b.__getslice__(      var_b.__repr__(          var_b.remove(
var_b.__gt__(            var_b.__reversed__(      var_b.reverse(
var_b.__hash__           var_b.__rmul__(          var_b.sort(
(Pdb) var_c
'prueba'
(Pdb) var_c.[TAB][TAB]
var_c.__add__(                      var_c.decode(
var_c.__class__(                    var_c.encode(
var_c.__contains__(                 var_c.endswith(
var_c.__delattr__(                  var_c.expandtabs(
var_c.__doc__                       var_c.find(
var_c.__eq__(                       var_c.format(
var_c.__format__(                   var_c.index(
var_c.__ge__(                       var_c.isalnum(
var_c.__getattribute__(             var_c.isalpha(
var_c.__getitem__(                  var_c.isdigit(
var_c.__getnewargs__(               var_c.islower(
var_c.__getslice__(                 var_c.isspace(
var_c.__gt__(                       var_c.istitle(
var_c.__hash__(                     var_c.isupper(
var_c.__init__(                     var_c.join(
var_c.__le__(                       var_c.ljust(
var_c.__len__(                      var_c.lower(
var_c.__lt__(                       var_c.lstrip(
var_c.__mod__(                      var_c.partition(
var_c.__mul__(                      var_c.replace(
var_c.__ne__(                       var_c.rfind(
var_c.__new__(                      var_c.rindex(
var_c.__reduce__(                   var_c.rjust(
var_c.__reduce_ex__(                var_c.rpartition(
var_c.__repr__(                     var_c.rsplit(
var_c.__rmod__(                     var_c.rstrip(
var_c.__rmul__(                     var_c.split(
var_c.__setattr__(                  var_c.splitlines(
var_c.__sizeof__(                   var_c.startswith(
var_c.__str__(                      var_c.strip(
var_c.__subclasshook__(             var_c.swapcase(
var_c._formatter_field_name_split(  var_c.title(
var_c._formatter_parser(            var_c.translate(
var_c.capitalize(                   var_c.upper(
var_c.center(                       var_c.zfill(
var_c.count(
```

Bueno, eso ya ayuda un poco más la tarea de debugging.

### Otras herramientas:

Puedes consultar la lista de Python Debuggers en la página oficial de Python:

- [PythonDebuggers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggers)

Comment: Super respuesta extra re contra excelentemente documented! Excellente.

Comment: Gracias @Elenasys ;-)

Answer (score 2):

PuDB tiene buena fama:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb

Espero que sea lo que necesitas.